# CSS: min-height and vertical-align:middle

Tags: css, html-table

How to force `min-height` and `vertical-align:middle` to work for `td` element or it's inner element?

Comment: i am not getting exactly what is your prob.. ?

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: i mean u want like this <td style="min-height:50px;vertical-align:middle">...</td> ??

Comment: put padding ... it will give you the effect but bad way to do it.

Comment: You know you can place multiple declarations in the same set of `{}`, right?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `height` on a `td` element is the equivalent of `min-height`, as a table cell will always stretch if required - but note that, especially in a complex table, that setting heights on table rows is a tricky, often impossible, process, browsers have a great deal of leeway in how they render tables and will often make a "judgement call"

```
td {
 height: 100px;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: But i need min-height. :) When i'm setting min-height for example for a div element which is inside td, everything is fine except vertical-align :) I need min-height, because i don't know exact height of elements inside.

Comment: a div, or any other element inside a `td` is a different story, even if you can set the height of it, which theoretically would be 100% of the 100% 'td` height anyway.. then you will not get the `vertical-align`.. as that property only applies to `td` itself and inline level elements - best to let the elements inside have no/auto height and that way they will use the td's vertical-align.. if you want a background or effect think about how you can use the the `td`.. an example would enable us to see what you're actually after ;)

Comment: +1 *I think* for absolute positioned td's, then `min-height` is the correct style. I had "frozen" column using absolute positioned td's and then rest are relative, so the absolute ones get `min-height` and the rest get `height`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always put a div inside the td and put the css rules in the div...

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: *;
```

Might do the job...

Answer (score 0):

To force min-height attribute for td you also can put invisible image in td, or wrap you td into div.
Example for first case:

```
<td><img style="float:left;min-height:50px;visibility:hidden;width:0px;">12345</td>
```